# MySQL server PID file could not be found Homebrew macOS 10.14

Tags: mysql, homebrew

I installed Mysql using homebrew.

run `mysql.server start`.

throw error:
`ERROR! MySQL server PID file could not be found!
Starting MySQL. ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file (/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid).`

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/480889/mysql-server-pid-file-could-not-be-found maybe that can help.